# Column Value Split and Split value create new value

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Database in Table in many Columns is created. One Column record the value of Two types of data in one Record. How to Split this Record into Columns. In this Column only the record is Like '%WEB%' then Split '-' this Symbol. Otherwise Null.

My Table Column Record like : WEBNOTE-053122, WEBEVV-121222, OCM-TIXOC2, OCM-LNTHEOCM

In this Record in I want one Column in WEBLIVE, WEBREC, OCM-TIXOC2, OCM-LNTHEOCM  and
The second Column in 053122, 121222, or this Second Column in Like '%OCM%' record is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split your string in the part before the "-" and the rest.

And use `CASE WHEN` to cover your two cases.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN yourcolumn LIKE '%WEB%' 
  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'-',1) 
  ELSE yourcolumn END AS column1,
CASE WHEN yourcolumn LIKE '%WEB%'
  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'-',-1) END AS column2
FROM yourtable;
```

Or if you want to point out in your query that the second column should be `NULL` if the string doesn't contain "WEB", you could add an `ELSE` clause:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN yourcolumn LIKE '%WEB%' 
  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'-',1) 
  ELSE yourcolumn END AS column1,
CASE WHEN yourcolumn LIKE '%WEB%'
  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'-',-1) 
  ELSE NULL END AS column2
FROM yourtable;
```

Your sample input:

| yourcolumn |
| --- |
| WEBNOTE-053122 |
| WEBEVV-121222 |
| OCM-TIXOC2 |
| OCM-LNTHEOCM |

The result of the query:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| WEBNOTE | 053122 |
| WEBEVV | 121222 |
| OCM-TIXOC2 |  |
| OCM-LNTHEOCM |  |

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LlKijWXz)

Comment: This is a great use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.